# How to edit message discord.py

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to edit message:

```
chat = client.get_channel(1007301750895677491)
msg = client.fetch_message(1007556250134917170)
await msg.edit(content=discord.File('week_result.png'))
```

But I am getting error:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-14' coro=<week_vipe() done, defined at main.py:80> exception=AttributeError("'coroutine' object has no attribute 'edit'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 164, in week_vipe
    await msg.edit(content=discord.File('week_result.png'))
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'edit'
```

Comment: You should be calling `await client.fetch_message(...)` since it's an async function. That is why you are getting an AttributeError. Also, you cannot change the attachments of a message after you have sent it. This can only be done by either using a link to the image and then changing your message content, or by using embeds.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass `content` an image [(read docs)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.edit)...

(P.S) In order to send an image and edit it later on you'll have to use embed messages... and then you'll be able to pass `message.edit` another argument (which is the embed) which will allow you to do so.